# Using createElement in JavaScript, how to add <p> and <span> inside of <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create sentences with a box next to them, where text can be dragged and dropped in the box.

So I want to create this HTML markup using only javascript:

```
<div>
  <p>Data1<span class = "smallBox droppable"></span></p>
  <p>Data 2<span class="smallBox droppable"></span></p>
</div>
```

That code functions and I'm able to drag and drop text into the boxes that are placed alongside the words "Data1" and "Data 2".

So far I have:

```js
var data2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

function dragDrop2(arr) {
  var length = arr.length;
  var list = document.createElement("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var spanning = document.createElement("span");
    spanning.classList.add("smallBox", "droppable", "draggable");

    paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
    paragraph.appendChild(spanning);
    list.appendChild(paragraph);

  }
  return list;
}

document.getElementById("example").appendChild(dragDrop2(data2));
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Right now, given my current javascript/html attempt, the drag/drop part isn't working in the boxes, and the I don't think the "span" tag is insie of the "p" tag, as my box is underneath each sentence.

If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it! Also, is there something that I can do to see the markup that is being created??
For example, create an alert that will show all the html markup, beginning at the original 'div id="example"?? (.html???)

Comment: If you `console.log` list before you return it does it look as expected?

Comment: check the browser developer tools (usually F12) to inspect the elements on your page

Comment: this code seems to work fine. May be you can post you drag and drop code that might help to figure out the actual issue.

Comment: Agreed it's making the elements as expected, but there's nothing here to make those classes special.

Comment: If you're using a plugin to make them draggable and droppable, make sure you do that *after* you add the dynamic elements.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong here, the code you've posted it's working fine.

Comment: May be is missing the part @Barmar has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

function dragDrop2(arr) {
  var length = arr.length;
  var list = document.createElement("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var spanning = document.createElement("span");
    spanning.classList.add("smallBox", "droppable", "draggable");

    spanning.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
    paragraph.appendChild(spanning);
    list.appendChild(paragraph);

  }
  return list;
}

document.getElementById("example").appendChild(dragDrop2(data2));
$( "span" ).draggable().droppable();
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

*I'm assuming you're using draggable and droppable from jquery ui*.

You must execute the `draggable` and `droppable` functions after creation of elements.

**Another key point is to change this:**

```
paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
```

**to this:**

```
spanning.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
```